# sed or awk - deleting strings between patterns

Tags: sed, awk, replace

I have a CSV file with lines like this:

```
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC.DDD,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE.FFF.GGGG,E-name,num1,num2,num3    
HHH.H-name,num1,num2,num3
...
```

Some lines have one identifier (like AAA); some have two (like CCC); some have three or more (like EEE).  And some identifiers are not three characters.  I need to remove all but the first identifier from each line of the line (such that the first period and anything that comes after it is deleted until the first comma is encountered), producing this:

```
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE,E-name,num1,num2,num3
HHH,H-name,num1,num2,num3
...
```

I've tried a few pattern-replace methods but am getting tripped up.  Does anyone have the syntax I need?

Comment: I think you have a problem with your HHH line. Shouldn't the first period be a comma? And shouldn't the "three or more" refer to EEE instead of HHH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl

```
$ perl -pe 's/\.[A-Z.]*?,/,/' input
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE,E-name,num1,num2,num3
HHH.H-name,num1,num2,num3
```

sed

```
$ sed 's/\.[A-Z.]*,/,/' input
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE,E-name,num1,num2,num3
HHH.H-name,num1,num2,num3
```

and awk

```
$ awk '/\./{sub(/\.[A-Z.]*,/, ",", $0)}{print}' input
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE,E-name,num1,num2,num3
HHH.H-name,num1,num2,num3
```

Comment: These could be problematic if there is only one identifier and a period appears in the name field. Nice and clear if the only periods appear in the identifier field, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^\([^.]\{1,\}\)[^,]*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove everything between a dot and the first colon. For the file

```
$ cat foo
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC.DDD,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE.FFF.GGGG,E-name,num1,num2,num3    
HHH.H-name,num1,num2,num3
```

use this sed command:

```
$ sed 's/\.[^,]*//' foo
AAA,A-name,num1,num2,num3
BBB,B-name,num1,num2,num3
CCC,C-name,num1,num2,num3
EEE,E-name,num1,num2,num3    
HHH,num1,num2,num3
```

However, it will remove an `H` at the last line. This seems to be a typo in your example, however.